# Parallax page not scrolling smoothly on chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am currently trying to make my portfolio website for my university project, however my parallax scrolling is not scrolling smoothly on google chrome, however I don't have any problems with safari..... 
Do you know why and what this might cause this problem and how I can fix it.

```css
/* this is my css code for my navigation bar. For example, you can change the background of the navigation bar */

#nav {
  background-color: transparent;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
}


/* this is the  css code for the links inside the navigation bar for example where to position the links they way they will look */

#nav a {
  float: left;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}


/* this is to change the background of the buttons(links) when they are on hover */

#nav a:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  text-shadow: 2px 2px rgb(0, 0, 255);
}

body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.8em;
  color: rgb(102, 102, 102);
}

.image1,
.image2,
.image3 {
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0.70;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.image1 {
  background-image: url(background1.jpg);
  min-height: 100%;
}

.image2 {
  background-image: url(background.jpg);
  min-height: 400px;
}

.image3 {
  background-image: url(ist.jpg);
  min-height: 400px;
}

.section {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 50px 80px;
}

.section-light {
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  color: #666;
}

.section-dark {
  background-color: rgb(40, 46, 52);
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

.text1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  font-size: 27px;
  letter-spacing: 8px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.text1 .border {
  background-color: #111;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
}

.text1 .border.trans {
  background-color: transparent;
}

@media(max-width:568px) {
  .image1,
  .image2,
  .image3 {
    background-attachment: scroll;
  }
}

.arrow-down {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.arrow-down::after {
  content: "";
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 820px;
  margin-left: 820px;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-right: 4px solid rgb(255, 0, 0);
  border-bottom: 4px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  animation: 3s arrow infinite ease;
}

@-webkit-keyframes arrow {
  0%,
  100% {
    top: 50px;
  }
  50% {
    top: 80px;
  }
}

@keyframes arrow {
  0%,
  100% {
    top: 50px;
  }
  50% {
    top: 80px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tangerine">



<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<!-- This is my code for my Navigation bar -->
<div id="nav">

  <a href="index.html">HOME</a>
  <a href="#about">ABOUT ME</a>
  <a href="myprojects.html">MY PROJECTS</a>
  <a href="mycv.html">MY CV</a>
  <a href="contactme.html">CONTACT</a>

</div>

<!-- this is my heading and the main background on my main page(Index) -->
<div class="image1">
  <div class="text1">
    <span class="border">
   Ivan Chamukov
   </span>
  </div>
</div>


<!-- this is my code for my scrolling arrow, the "onclick" makes my class/object clickable -->
<div class="arrow-down" onclick="slideDown()"></div>



<!-- this is my page - About me, and the information about me. -->
<section class="section section-light">
  <h2> About me</h2>
  <p class="about">My name is Ivan Chamukov. I am computer science student at Goldsmiths, University of London. I have studied BTEC Level 3 Extended Diplopma in Travel and Tourism and graduated in 2017 with grade D*D*D. I used to train triathlon professionally and take
    part in national competitions in Bulgaria and United Kingdom.My name is Ivan Chamukov. I am computer science student at Goldsmiths, University of London. I have studied BTEC Level 3 Extended Diplopma in Travel and Tourism and graduated in 2017 with
    grade D*D*D. I used to train triathlon professionally and take part in national competitions in Bulgaria and United Kingdom.My name is Ivan Chamukov. I am computer science student at Goldsmiths, University of London. I have studied BTEC Level 3 Extended
    Diplopma in Travel and Tourism and graduated in 2017 with grade D*D*D. I used to train triathlon professionally and take part in national competitions in Bulgaria and United Kingdom. </p>
</section>


<div class="image2">
  <div class="text1">
    <span class="border">
   Image Two Text
   </span>

  </div>

</div>

<section class="section section-dark">
  <h2> Section Two </h2>
  <p>n this video we will be building a very basic implementation of a parallax website with fixed scrolling using HTML and CSS. We will make it so that we can scroll and the images will stay in place. We will also learn some other basic HTML and CSS tips
    along the way</p>



</section>


<div class="image3">
  <div class="text1">
    <span class="border">
   Image three text
   </span>

  </div>
</div>


<section class="section section-dark">
  <h2> Section Three </h2>
  <p>n this video we will be building a very basic implementation of a parallax website with fixed scrolling using HTML and CSS. We will make it so that we can scroll and the images will stay in place. We will also learn some other basic HTML and CSS tips
    along the way</p>

</section>

<div class="image2">
  <div class="text1">
    <span class="border">
   Ivan Chamukov
   </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you actually link to the page itself if it's public?

Comment: @ReyHaynes sorry, you can use this link to see the website I have uploaded it to my uni server.. please open it on full screen as it is not completed yet.. 
http://doc.gold.ac.uk/~icham002/Finalproject3copy/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The background image of the snowy mountains with the sled is almost **17 MB** large. Parallax effects usually cause repainting on the browser. Repainting something that huge is a performance nightmare.

Reducing the file size of `background1.jpg` would help tremendously.